# What is the difference between the US and global edition of the AIMA book by Russell and Norvig?

Tags: comparison, books, norvig-russell

The book *Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach* by Russell and Norvig has two editions: global and the US. It looks like these two are generally the same, but have some differences in the order of the chapters and in the context, is this correct?

Comment: they only add one chapter in the [Global Edition](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/global-index.html) adding the chapter 20 Knowledge in Learning, in the V Machine Learning Section and start change the orders of the chapters in the Section IV Uncertain knowledge and reasoning. I don't have those editions yet to confirm if there are any differences between the sub-chapters, if anyone have it please answer about the difference. for the moment  [Global Edition](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/global-index.html) has an extra chapter than [US edition](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/).

Answer (score 6):

I check again with the subchapters of Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach, 4th Global ed / US ed from [this website](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/) the pdf subchapters reference of [Global Edition](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/global-Contents.pdf) and [US Edition](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/). I can confirm you the difference between Global US edition is this subchapter:

```
20 Knowledge in Learning 739
    20.1 A Logical Formulation of Learning 739
    20.2 Knowledge in Learning 747
    20.3 Explanation-Based Learning 750
    20.4 Learning Using Relevance Information 754
    20.5 Inductive Logic Programming 758
Summary 767
Bibliographical and Historical Notes 768
```

So Global Edition has more content than US Edition.

Answer (score 1):

The difference can be found in the following link more clearly

[US vs Global](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/global-index.html)

Comment: Thanks but I have seen the site before. Now I am familiar with the difference.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/21434)